# how to paste a segment of code from another file?

Tags: javascript, react-native

This might be a weird question to ask but is there a way to paste/import a segment of code from another file?
for example:

file1.js:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
   some_paste_function('file2.js');
  );
}
```

file2.js:

```
<View>
       <View>
         <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>
</View>
```

basically the `some_paste_function(file_name);` just pastes the content of the file2.js in the functions place, it's more for making the file system look cleaner rather than using `import`

is there such a function or anything similar to it in react native or even js in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Technically* you can use `require` to dynamically load contents from another file, if they are exported from it, and only if you're running on a module loader that uses it.

```js
export default function App() {
  return require("./file2.js");
}
```

```
export default function Component() {
  return <View>
    {/* ... */}
  </View>;
}
```

However, I'd strongly advise against it, as you lose the benefits of proper type checking, auto-refactoring and your dependancy graph gets messy.

Comment: thanks! and also thanks for telling me why it's not ideal, most people leave out that detail